# SASS Assign by reference

Tags: sass

I am building a system to take default stylesheets, and merge with a theme, and a base theme to produce the final site css, however i was hoping to find a way to assign variables by reference, not by value so i can do things like this.

base.vars.scss

```
$PrimaryFg: blue
$LinkFg: $PrimaryFg
$DefaultFont: opensans
$HeadingFont: $DefaultFont
```

basetheme.vars.scss

```
$PrimaryFg: yellow
$CaptionFont: $HeadingFont
```

theme.vars.scss

```
$DefaultFont: Verdana
```

base.rules.scss

```
body {font: $DefaultFont }
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font: $HeadingFont; }
a {color: $LinkFg }
```

basetheme.rules.scss

```
caption {font: $CaptionFont; }
```

theme.rules.scss

```
@import 'base.vars.scss';
@import 'basetheme.vars.scss';
@import 'theme.vars.scss';
@import 'base.rules.scss';
@import 'basetheme.rules.scss';
```

The main problem i have is that, $HeadingFont will be set to opensans, and wont change to Verdana, and the link FG colour will still be blue,

I cant find a solution, i was hoping that the $HeadingFont: $DefaultFont, would not assign the value immediately, but assign the variable, so it could be changed later.

Yes i am aware of !default, however it is a complete mess trying to do this with !default.

Comment: The variable placeholders `$xxx` simply get string replaced at the time of compilation. CSS isn't a language where you can pass things around by reference, it's all text and number values. If you want things to be overridable, they're going to have to be text and number values. Frameworks like Bootstrap and Foundation follow this approach.

Comment: What's the issue with using `!default`? That is the intention behind this feature, so if it's become an issue you're probably using it wrong.

Comment: Using Default in the example above leads to a huge mess, how do i base a colour on the LinkFg in the theme base, while overriding PrimaryFG and then also LinkFg, etc in the actual theme. It would be ideal of there was an operator that instead of copying the value of a variable now, it waited until all files had been processed to copy that value. eg ```$LinkFg: $PrimaryFg !late;``` or something similar.